# Custom function for WSS 3.0 calculated columns

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007, wss, wss-3.0

Is there any way I can add a custom function to WSS 3.0 that can be used in calculated fields?

For example, I want to add a function that URL Encodes strings, so that the users can create columns with the URLs based on the other fields something like this:

```
"http://www.test.com?fname="&URLENCODE([FirstName])&"&lname="&URLENCODE([LastName])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you can only use the pre-defined functions for calculated fields. (See a list of functions [here](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-sharepoint-services-help/examples-of-common-formulas-HA001160947.aspx))

There a some things you can do, depending on how much work you are willing to put on this.

First, you could a script to encode parts of your URL. Here is a [thorough example](http://sharepointjavascript.wordpress.com/2009/10/15/reformat-url-from-calculated-column-with-decent-clickable-link-text/). It is not very generic, but it will work very well for a column.

Second option is to fill the column yourself by catching the SPItemEventReceiver functions for the lists where the column you are creating is used. 
You would have to catch the [ItemAdded](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spitemeventreceiver.itemadded.aspx) event and then encode the URL in server-side code. See other events [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spitemeventreceiver_members.aspx).

So yeah, not as easy as it could be, but possible.